# Error message is shown when opening the terminal (bash) in the Mac

Tags: bash

I used to install mysql in my mac. Now I have forgotten details about installation. 
But after installing mysql, the error message will be shown in my bash when I open the terminal in my Mac. (See the details below)

```
Last login: Tue Jan  7 21:19:26 on ttys000
-bash: export: `=': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin': not a valid identifier
```

I doubt whether the error is related with the environment variable.However, I checked the $PATH, it seems normal.

```
jake ~ $ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

Any one can help me fix this problem ?

Many thanks !

Comment: whats in your bashrc

Comment: bash does not like spaces between var_name=var_value

Answer (score 1):

You have in either .bashr_profile or .bashrc an expoert statement, where there is a space between the variable and the equal sign.